# Nhibernate - 2 - Level of Master Details - Insert in one UnitOfWork

Tags: nhibernate, aggregate, unit-of-work, master-detail

Mappings Code for ObservationUnits:

```
        Table("ObservationUnits");
        Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Id)
          .Column("ID")
          .CustomType("Guid")
          .Access.Property()
          .CustomSqlType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.GuidComb()
          ;

        ......Other Mappings.....

        Map(x => x.Number)
          .Column("Number")
          .CustomType("int")
          .Access.Property()
          .Generated.Never()
          .Not.Nullable()
          .CustomSqlType("INT")
          ;

        HasMany(x => x.Partitions)
            .Access.Property()
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade.DeleteOrphan()
            .LazyLoad()
            //.OptimisticLock().Version()
            .Inverse()
            .OrderBy("ID ASC")
            .Generic()
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Partitions_ObservationUnits")
            .KeyColumns.Add("PartitionID", mapping => mapping.Name("PartitionID")
                .SqlType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
                .Not.Nullable())
            ;
```

Mappings Code for Partitions:

```
        Table("Partitions");
        Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Id)
          .Column("ID")
          .CustomType("Guid")
          .Access.Property()
          .CustomSqlType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.GuidComb()
          ;

        ......Other Mappings.....

        References(x => x.ObservationUnit)
            .Class<ObservationUnit>()
            .Access.Property()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Columns("ObservationUnitID")
            ;

        HasMany(x => x.Fragments)
            .Access.Property()
            .AsSet()
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad()
            //.OptimisticLock().Version()
            .Inverse()
            .OrderBy("Number ASC")
            .Generic()
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Fragments_Partitions")
            .KeyColumns.Add("PartitionID", mapping => mapping.Name("PartitionID")
                .SqlType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
                .Not.Nullable())
            ;
```

Mappings Code for Fragments(It is inheritance type Mapping):

```
        Table("Fragments");
        Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();
        LazyLoad();
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();

        Id(x => x.Id)
          .Column("ID")
          .CustomType("Guid")
          .Access.Property()
          .CustomSqlType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.GuidComb()
          ;

     ......Other Mappings.....

        References(x => x.Partition)
            .Class<Partition>()
            .Access.Property()
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Columns("PartitionID")
            ;
```

Hello everyone,

I am wondering if there is any way to place the below 2 mentioned scenario using the above Mapping to FNH between the tables "ObservationUnit"-"Partition"-"Fragment".

Scenario 1:
Sententiously insert to all of them ONE record. 
1 Rec to Observation Unit
1 Rec to Partition
1 Rec to Fragment

using only ONE commit into the UnitOfWork (it is implemented the repository pattern)
The commit will be placed to the ObservationUnit (It is Aggregate for all the rest).
For example: if the commit failed (none record for the ObservationUnit Entity) a rollback should be placed that avoid any persistent change between both Partition and Fragment tables.

Scenario 2:
Sententiously insert to all of them more that one records. 
1 Rec to Observation Unit
3(for example) Recs to Partition
4(for example) Recs to Fragment

Again, using only ONE commit into the UnitOfWork, commit will be placed to the ObservationUnit (It is Aggregate for all the rest). Any fail should remove any insertion.

Any help? 
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly straight forward if your UnitOfWork / repository supports transactions.
Since NHibernates ISession already is a UnitOfWork I use it in my example:

```
using(var session = OpenSession())
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var observationUnit = new ObserVationUnit{ /* fill it */};
    var partition = new Partition { ObservationUnit = observationUnit, /* fill the rest */ };
    var fragment = new Fragment { Partition = partition, /* fill the rest */ };
    session.Save(observationUnit);
    session.Save(partition);
    session.Save(fragment);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Only saving fragment should also work.